# mysql max function does not work in joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla, max

someone can tell me what is wrong in this code? I just want to get the last date in Joomla 2.5. Thanks

```
    // Get a db connection.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query
    ->select($db->quoteName('MAX(created)'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))


    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();

    return $result;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't quote functions:

```
$query
    ->select('MAX('.$db->quoteName('created').')')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
```

Comment: @agustinBaraza - Please accept the answer to mark the question as solved by clicking the "tick" icon

Answer (score 0):

A `;` is missing at the end of the line  `->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))`